# PHP Convert seconds to milliseconds, seconds or minutes

Tags: php, curl, numbers, milliseconds, seconds

I am developing a script that checks the total time of loading a file (images,css,js) using CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME.

The result is generated in seconds but apears like

```
 0.022919 seconds
 0.123219 seconds
 1.3663 seconds
```

I want to convert the output to milliseconds if the output is less than 1 second then should apears something like this.

```
 0.022919 seconds = 22 ms
 0.123219 seconds = 12 ms
 1.3663 seconds = 1 second
```

Comment: seconds to milliseconds = seconds * 1000..... mathematics 101; so something as basic as `$time = ($seconds >= 1.0) ? $seconds . 's' : ($seconds * 1000) . 'ms';`

Comment: Exactly as @MarkBaker stated. Do the basic math and echo out the desired output as you stated there.

Comment: It generates this :  `0.000539 = 0.815ms  |  0.044395 = 47.907ms | 0.000353 = 0.363ms`

Comment: You're clearly using some obscure branch of mathematics if 0.000539 /1000 gives 0.815ms - real maths works more like [this](https://3v4l.org/ue47r)

Comment: Was my fault sorry: This is what I am getting `22.291ms = 0.022291 | 0.453ms = 0.000453 | 0.57ms = 0.00057` for example the 0.57ms should become 5 ms ? I need them without decimals

Comment: How does 0.00057 which gives 0.57ms become 5ms? This feels like you're changing the rules of mathematics again

Comment: haha, I know, the idea is I want to display ms and seconds without decimals, but I think is not prosible

Comment: It's perfectly possible, `$time = ($seconds >= 1.0) ? floor($seconds) . 's' : floor($seconds * 1000) . 'ms';`..... but `0.00057` will give you `0ms`, not `5ms`